# search substring within a string and return next word

Tags: linux, search

I have this string where I want to search for a keyword and then return the following word.

```
"SELECT \"city\",\"temp_lo\",\"temp_hi\",\"date\" FROM schema_name.\"weather_7\""
```

I want to return "schema_name" and the only indicating text is the preceding "FROM " string.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For exactly the setup given, try

```
sed 's/^.*FROM //; s/\..*$//' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `schema_name` consists of a sequence of *word characters*, if your grep supports Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE) you could use

```
grep -Po 'FROM\s+\K\w+'
```

Ex.

```
echo '"SELECT \"city\",\"temp_lo\",\"temp_hi\",\"date\" FROM schema_name.\"weather_7\""' |
  grep -Po 'FROM\s+\K\w+'
schema_name
```